# mongoose.findOne() returns null

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I want to check if user's id is in the database and if yes return message.
My current code which is creating a new data even when user already has his ID in the database:

```js
let user = message.mentions.members.first() || bot.users.cache.get(args[0])
let userid = user.user.id

Data.findOne({
     userID: userid,
     serverID: message.guild.id,
     name: user.user.username,
     language: args[2],
     email: args[1],
      lb: "all",
}, (err, data) => {
     if (err) return console.log(err);

     if (!data) {
            const newData = new Data({
                name: user.user.tag,
                language: args[2],
                email: args[1],
                userID: userid,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                lb: "all"
            })
            newData.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
            return message.channel.send("new data created")

        } else {
            if (data.userID === user.user.id) return message.reply("Already has his data.")
}
})
```

And here is my mongoose scheme code:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    language: String,
    email: String,
    userID: String,
    serverID: String,
    lb: String,
    usage: Number
})

module.exports = mongoose.model(`Data`, dataSchema)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use all those conditions in `findOne()` you just need to use 1 unique identifier, which is `userID` in this case.

That's the reason it's not working as intended, unless all the conditions are the same as the ones in the existing user data it won't find it.

```js
Data.findOne({
     userID: userid
}, (err, data) => {
     // do something
})
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks! Do you have any explanation why it worked ?

Comment: I added an explanation in the answer. What I'm guessing happened is, you created the document with certain data, when you did it again, you didn't do it with the exact same data and therefore not all conditions in `findOne()` were met leading it to say there wasn't an existing document and that it has to create one.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Thanks again!